# Using span margins to align text

Tags: html, css

A little new to html so if further explanation is necessary or this question just doesn't make sense please feel free to say so.

I am using div to layout a webform I am designing and using the &nbsp to move text within a div doesnt always produce the result I want as far as the layout of the page.

I started experimenting and by using:

```
<span style="margin-left:(variable)px"></span>
```

i am able to move the text exactly where I want it.

My question is this, is this a bad practice? is there a better way to do what I am trying to do, or a more conventional way? Or even something built into html that I just have not discovered yet.

Thank you

*** Added Block of code to show what i am trying to accomplish

```
   Complainant's Address
   <input type="text" size="50" id="complainantAddress"/> 
   <span style="margin-left:3px"></span>
   City
   <input type="text" name="city" maxlength="15" size="15"/>
   <span style="margin-left:16px"></span>
   State
   </div>
```

Comment: it may be useful if you posted a sample of your code, but using css for spacing is definitly much better than lots of non-braking spaces!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using non breakable spaces for layout/positioning is bad practice.
What you are trying to do with `style` attributes is better, but inline-style attributes are often considered as bad pratice, too.
Style attributes are hard to maintain and you duplicate lots of information etc. In addition this styling has the highest specificity and cannot be overwritten by other styles (like user CSS files). They should be used with caution.

Use CSS attributes `margin`, `padding` and `text-align` for this.

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/UYUA7/

**HTML**

```
Text<br />

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text <!-- Do NOT use this -->

<div class="center">Center</div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="indent">Indented</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

.indent {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I even up-voted. :) My only concern is that you've said that "inline-style attributes are bad practice" which isn't really the case. Using inline-styles for one-off elements is perfectly acceptable. Not everything needs to be marked up with ids and classes.

Comment: @DeviantSeev There may be a few cases, where inline-styling is acceptable. In general it is bad practice and you shouldn't learn it this way, when you are starting to _learn CSS_. -- I strongly prefer the strict detachment of content/structure and styling.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree with you. Just because you prefer something to be done in a certain way, doesn't make the other way a 'bad practice'. I am actually in favor of primarily using classes for styling but calling inline-styling bad practice is a stretch. There is no rule that says that every single element needs to be styled by a class or id. In fact, doing so will make your style sheet unnecessarily bloated and harder to follow. Just my two cents.

Comment: @DeviantSeev I'm usually working with templates and customer-specific designs (30+). Maybe we can agree on this: _"inline-style attributes are often considered as bad pratice ... They should be used with caution."_

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. Just kidding, it's stupid to argue this point because it's just semantics. An experienced developer will know when to use an inline-style and when to use a class. That's all it comes down to for me. For you it might be different and that's ok. :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is actually a better way to do spacing, than relying on &nbsps. This will give you a much greater flexibility in the long-term and allow you to make changes quicker. (Less typing)

The only other thing that I would recommend is to read through this CSS manual:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp

This will help you continue to learn about position with css.

UPDATE:

This is what your code can look like:

**CSS** - Use it in the header

```
<style type="text/css">
#complainantAddress {
    margin-right: 3px;
}

#city {
    margin-right: 16px;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
Complainant's Address: <input type="text" size="50" id="complainantAddress"/> 
City: <input type="text" name="city" maxlength="15" size="15" id="city"/>
```

Notice that I created two css styles, one for each matching input boxes. Within each style I defined a margin which would add the appropriate spacing to the right of the input box.

So the first input box called "complainantAddress" will have 3px spacing to the right and the second one who's id is "city" will have 16px spacing to the right of it.